# Implementing Enhanced Ecommerce: How to Retrieve Product Data?

Tags: magento, google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-datalayer

Can someone please help me on how to implement the data retrieval from my shopping cart to be sent to UA? This would include product data, transaction, impression, etc. I'm using Magento.

From my understanding, I'm supposed to add different codes to different pages of my store. For example, to measure how many times the user clicked on a product, I'd add the following code to my product page template (code found on Google Enhanced Ecommerce):

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {                       // Provide product details in a productFieldObject.
  'id': '**WHAT DO I PUT HERE?**',           // Product ID (string).
  'name': '**WHAT DO I PUT HERE?**',        // Product name (string).
  'category': '**WHAT DO I PUT HERE?**',    // Product category (string).
  'brand': '**WHAT DO I PUT HERE?**',       // Product brand (string).
  'variant': '**WHAT DO I PUT HERE?**',     // Product variant (string).
  'position': **WHAT DO I PUT HERE?**,      // Product position (number).
  'dimension1': '**WHAT DO I PUT HERE?**'   // Custom dimension (string).
});    

ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {              // click action.
  'list': '**WHAT DO I PUT HERE?**'         // Product list (string).
});
```

1.) Is there a general productFieldObject template that I can insert to the product page? If so, what do I replace the WHAT DO I PUT HERE? section with?

2.) My confusion is how Analytics retrieves the product data (I'm using Magento). If there's a productFieldObject template, then after ec:addProduct fires, it has to go somewhere to retrieve all the product info. Can someone please tell me how to do that?

In all of the Enhanced Ecommerce implementation examples, the guides have already populated the productFieldObject snippet with the actual product details. None of the guides explains how to get Analytics to retrieve the product data.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could teach me how to do that. I've been reading and have really hit a dead end...

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Magento makes it extremely easy for you. You don't need to do any of the things you listed above because its already built in.

In the Magento admin go to System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Google API -> Google Analytics

Then just put in your UA number in the box. If you've already added Google Analytics somewhere else in your site, like in the head.phtml file or any other files, be sure to remove it, otherwise it will be counted twice, and you'll see twice the number of pageviews as you actually have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm actually referring to implementing Enhanced Ecommerce within Magento, not just Google Analytics. I've tried using the Magento Enhanced Ecommerce plugin but heard it was very limited, so didn't end up using it ...

Comment: This is for Enhanced Ecommerce, its all built in to the file Ga.php which is found in the app/code/core/mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block folder. All of the methods you're looking for are found in that file, and all start with $order->..... I've pasted the full file for you to check out in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hn2k0538/

Comment: Oh ok! I'll go take a look right now :). This is very exciting news. I'm seeing light at the end of the tunnel!

What do I do with all these codes that you pasted though...?

OH, I have Community edition.. I noticed the codes were from Enterprise edition. Are they still the same?

Comment: Magento out of the box doesn't give you full blown solution, you might need to try community extensions to get best out of Google Enhanced E-commerce Tracking